# How to use RenderTreeBuilder for RenderFragment<> in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

I am implementing an `EventCallback` in a `RenderFragment` parameter to enable an external close button to fire an event within a custom component:

```cs
public RenderFragment<IElementInfo>? ContentTemplate { get; set; }
```

Here is the interface:

```cs
public interface IElementInfo
{
    EventCallback CloseCallback { get; }
}
```

And to use:

```html
<ContentTemplate>
    <button type="button"
            @onclick="@(async () =>
              await RaiseCallback(context.CloseCallback))">
        Cancel
    </button>
</ContentTemplate>
```

**[edit]**
This is what the compiler generates for the above usage:

```cs
__builder.AddAttribute<ClosedEventArgs>(22, "Closed", RuntimeHelpers.TypeCheck<EventCallback<ClosedEventArgs>>(EventCallback.Factory.Create<ClosedEventArgs>((object) this, new Action(OnClosed))));
```

**[end edit]**

There is more code that is needed to wire it all up. **As it is it works.**

What I am trying to do is add a simple method for passing a title and a razor component to wire-up using the `RenderTreeBuilder` manually. Here is a working version for a non-generic `RenderFragment`:

**[edit]**

```cs
public void Show(string? title, Type contentType)
{
    if (contentType.BaseType != typeof(ComponentBase))
        throw new ArgumentException
            ($"{contentType.FullName} must be a Blazor Component");

    RenderFragment content = x =>
    {
        x.OpenComponent(1, contentType);
        x.CloseComponent();
    };

    Show(new Options
    {
        HeaderText = title,
        ContentTemplate = content
     });
}

public void Show(Options options)
{
    Container container = new Container(options, _provider);
    _contents.Add(container);

    // notify new content
    OnUpdated?.Invoke();
}
```

Sample usage:

```cs
Service.Show(
    "Sample Title",
    typeof(SampleRazorFile));
// where SampleRazorFile is a seperate razor file
```

**[end edit]**

Where I am stumped is with changing with the `RenderTreeBuilder` for working with the generic `RenderFragment<IElementInfo>`.

**[edit]**

The question is regarding `RenderTreeBuilder` - can it return a `Renderfragment<TValue>` type?

**[end edit]**

There is next to no information out there on this specific task. Has anyone done anything like this and have any suggestions?

Comment: Why is IElementInfo.CloseCallback defined as an EventCallback - that seems like the wrong type - why not Action?

Comment: It is to do with events. The code works fine. Event if I changed from what I am using to using an `Action`, I still have the same issue with the return type `Renderfragment<TValue>` from `RenderTreeBuilder`.

Comment: The code works fine? Ok, sorry to bother you then.

Comment: Razor code works fine. The issue is manually with `RenderTreeBuilder`.

Answer (score 2):

<s>I have concluded that you can not do it. I have added solutions to support both `RenderFragment` and `RenderFragment<TValue>`.</s>

Actually, the solution is unexpectedly simple - cast the `RenderFragment` to the generic type.

So, for my example above, the answer is as follows:

```cs
ContentTemplate = (RenderFragment<IElementInfo>)(_context =>
    builder =>
    {
        builder.OpenElement(2, "div");
        // trimmed...
        builder.CloseElement();
    }
);
```

How I found this solution was to enable emitting of Roslyn generated files. Add the following to the project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Hope that this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely sure of your context and if you have it right.  You don't set the "context" externally, you set it within the component and pass it to the external RenderFragment block.

Here's some code for a component to display the WeatherForecast rows in `FetchData` that demonstreates how to use the `RenderFragment<>` in a RenderFragment block.

```
<h3>ListOfWeather</h3>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        @this.HeaderTemplate
    </thead>
    @this.Rows
</table>

@code {
    [Parameter] public List<WeatherForecast> ForecastList { get; set; } = new List<WeatherForecast>();

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<WeatherForecast>? ListRowTemplate { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<WeatherForecast>? HeaderTemplate { get; set; }

    private RenderFragment Rows => (builder) =>
    {
        if (this.ListRowTemplate is null)
            return;

        builder.OpenElement(0, "tdbody");
        foreach (var forecast in ForecastList)
            builder.AddContent(2, this.ListRowTemplate(forecast));

        builder.CloseElement();
    };
}
```

For reference `FetchData` looks like this:

```
@page "/fetchdata"

<PageTitle>Weather forecast</PageTitle>

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from a service.</p>

<ListOfWeather ForecastList="this.Forecasts">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Temp. (C)</th>
            <th>Temp. (F)</th>
            <th>Summary</th>
        </tr>

    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ListRowTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>@context.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
            <td>@context.TemperatureC</td>
            <td>@context.TemperatureF</td>
            <td>@context.Summary</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </ListRowTemplate>
</ListOfWeather>

@code {
    private List<WeatherForecast> Forecasts = new List<WeatherForecast>();

    [Inject] private WeatherForecastService? service { get; set; }
    private WeatherForecastService Service => service!;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        this.Forecasts = await Service.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed what I explained - this works, I need to implement it manually.  I have a `Context` exposed for a callback via the `Renderfragment<TValue>` Template. This is normal practice. ref:  [ASP.NET Core Blazor templated components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-6.0)